# Can't prove $(B\oplus C)\cap D=(B\cap D)\oplus (C\cap D)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove $(B\oplus C)\cap D=(B\cap D)\oplus (C\cap D)$.

> Note: $B\oplus C=(B\cup C)-(B\cap C)$ and $B-C=B\cap C^C$.

I have tried to prove it as below.

\begin{align*}
(B\oplus C)\cap D &= ((B\cup C)-(B\cap C))\cap D\\
&=((B\cup C)\cap(B\cap C)^C)\cap D\\
&=((B\cup C)\cap D\cap(B\cap C)^C)\\
&=((B\cap D)\cup (C\cap D))\cap(B\cap C)^C\\
&=((B\cap D)\cup (C\cap D))-(B\cap C)... (1)
\end{align*}

I'm stuck to get right hand side. Now I try to expand from right hand side as below.

\begin{align*}
(B\cap D)\oplus (C\cap D)&= ((B\cap D)\cup (C\cap D))-((B\cap D)\cap (C\cap D)) ...(2)
\end{align*}

Now I stuck to prove it, because I can't get eq (1)= eq (2).
Anyone can give me hint to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just one more fact you need to get from your last line to the right hand side.
Since $(B\cap D) \cup (C \cap D)$ is a subset of $D$, you can write:

$$(B\cap D) \cup (C \cap D) - (B\cap C) = (B\cap D) \cup (C \cap D) - (B\cap C)\cap D$$

Now $D = D\cap D$, so using associativity and commutativity of the intersection, you can write:

$$(B\cap D) \cup (C \cap D) - (B\cap C)\cap D = (B\cap D) \cup (C \cap D) - (B\cap D\cap C \cap D)$$

So changing the last term with $(B\cap D\cap C \cap D) = (B\cap D)\cap (C \cap D)$, you get the symmetric difference $(B\cap D)\oplus(C\cap D)$ on the right.